# What does "replacement" refer to in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm translating an article about [wearable smart watches](http://www.phonearena.com/news/To-wearable-or-not-to-wearable_id64018).  What does "replacement" mean? And what does it refer to in the following context?

> [snip:  (*The author is unsatisfied, because of the high battery consumption of smart watches.*)]
>
> That is the single most pressing reason why I am not going to bother
>   bringing any of my Android Wear stuff to CES next month because it is
>   just one more cable, one more charger, and one more item that I will
>   either forget to use, or just as bad, I will end up leaving it at the
>   hotel where I then have to chase it down to have it sent home, or
>   spend some money to replace the part.  Of course, the smartwatch won't
>   have enough battery life to stay "on" while **the replacement is en
>   route either**.

Comment: I think that this question is more about understanding a fairly complicated sentence than about understanding the dictionary definition of replacement, so I am voting to leave this open.

Answer (score 2):

It is [***replacement***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/replacement) sense 2:

> 2) a person or thing that takes the place of another, esp. of one that has worn out, broken down, etc.

In this context, it has to be a new charger that is being sent to you. And it is saying that you won't have one until you receive it.